# Rewrite a non-linear first order differential equation to a linear differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

Given this non-linear first order differential equation:

$$y' + f(x)y + g(x)y^n = 0.$$

How do I rewrite this to a linear differential equation by using the following substitution:

$u = y^{1-n}$.

I know that it might be helpful to first express $u'$ in terms of $y$ and $y'$ but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Yes, you do exactly that. What do you get? This type of equations is named after Bernoulli (I do not know which one of the dynasty).

Comment: I get $u' = (1-n)y^{-n}y'$ and I think I actually just found out what to do next. I divided the equation by $y^n$ and then I can substitute $u$ and $\frac{u'}{1-n}$.

Comment: I found the linear differential equation $\frac{1}{1-n}u' + f(x)u = -g(x)$. This equation is homogenous and has order 1, right?

Comment: Yes. Now you can at least write the solution in terms of direct integrations (that is, not integral equations).